# Getting standardized coefficients for a glmer model?

Tags: r, lme4

I've been asked to provide standardized coefficients for a `glmer` model, but am not sure how to obtain them. Unfortunately, the [`beta`](https://rdrr.io/cran/reghelper/man/beta.html) function  does not work on `glmer` models:

```
Error in UseMethod("beta") : 
  no applicable method for 'beta' applied to an object of class "c('glmerMod', 'merMod')"
```

Are there other functions I could use, or would I have to write one myself?

Another problem is that the model contains several continuous predictors (which operate on similar scales) and 2 categorical predictors (one with 4 levels, one with six levels). The purpose of using the standardized coefficients would be to compare the impact of the categorical predictors to those of the continuous ones, and I'm not sure that standardized coefficients are the appropriate way to do so. Are standardized coefficients an acceptable approach?

The model is as follows:

```
model=glmer(cbind(nr_corr,maximum-nr_corr) ~ (condition|SUBJECT) + categorical_1 + categorical_2 + continuous_1 + continuous_2 + continuous_3 + continuous_4 + categorical_1:categorical_2 + categorical_1:continuous_3, data, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=100000)), family = binomial)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reghelper::beta` simply standardizes the numeric variables in our dataset. So assuming your catagorical variables are `factor`s rather than numeric dummy variables or other contrast encodings we can fairly simply standardize the numeric variables in our dataset

```
vars <- grep('^continuous(.*)?', all.vars(formula(model)))
f <- function(var, data)
   scale(data[[var]])
data[, vars] <- lapply(vars, f, data = data)
update(model, data = data)
```

Now for the more general case we can more or less just as easily create our own `beta.merMod` function. However we will need to take into account whether or not it makes sense to standardize `y`. For example if we have a `poisson` model only positive integer values makes sense. In addition a question becomes whether or not to scale the random slope effects or not, and whether it makes sense to ask this question in the first place. In it I assume that categorical variables are encoded as `character` or `factor` and not `numeric` or `integer`.

```
beta.merMod <- function(model, 
                        x = TRUE, 
                        y = !family(model) %in% c('binomial', 'poisson'), 
                        ran_eff = FALSE, 
                        skip = NULL, 
                        ...){
  # Extract all names from the model formula
  vars <- all.vars(form <- formula(model))
  lhs <- all.vars(form[[2]])
  # Get random effects from the 
  ranef <- names(ranef(model))
  # Remove ranef and lhs from vars
  rhs <- vars[!vars %in% c(lhs, ranef)]
  # extract the data used for the model
  env <- environment(form)
  call <- getCall(model)
  data <- get(dname <- as.character(call$data), envir = env)
  # standardize the dataset
  vars <- character()
  if(isTRUE(x))
    vars <- c(vars, rhs)
  if(isTRUE(y))
    vars <- c(vars, lhs)
  if(isTRUE(ran_eff))
    vars <- c(vars, ranef)
  data[, vars] <- lapply(vars, function(var){
    if(is.numeric(data[[var]]))
      data[[var]] <- scale(data[[var]])
    data[[var]]
  })
  # Update the model and change the data into the new data.
  update(model, data = data)
}
```

The function works for both **linear** and **generalized linear** mixed effect models (not tested for nonlinear models), and is used just like other beta functions from `reghelper`

```
library(reghelper)
library(lme4)
# Linear mixed effect model
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fm2 <- beta(fm1)
fixef(fm1) - fixef(fm2)
(Intercept)        Days 
  -47.10279   -19.68157 

# Generalized mixed effect model
data(cbpp)
# create numeric variable correlated with period
cbpp$nv <- 
  rnorm(nrow(cbpp), mean = as.numeric(levels(cbpp$period))[as.numeric(cbpp$period)])
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ nv + (1 | herd),
              family = binomial, data = cbpp)
gm2 <- beta(gm1)
fixef(gm1) - fixef(gm2)
(Intercept)          nv 
  0.5946322   0.1401114
```

Note however that unlike `beta` the function returns the **updated model** not a summary of the model.

> Another problem is that the model contains several continuous predictors (which operate on similar scales) and 2 categorical predictors (one with 4 levels, one with six levels). The purpose of using the standardized coefficients would be to compare the impact of the categorical predictors to those of the continuous ones, and I'm not sure that standardized coefficients are the appropriate way to do so. Are standardized coefficients an acceptable approach?

Now that is a great question and one better suited for `stats.stackexchange`, and not one I'm certain of the answer to.

Comment: Thank you so much, Oliver! I'm still trying to wrap my head around all this. May I ask what exactly the line 'cbpp$nv <- 
  rnorm(nrow(cbpp), mean = as.numeric(levels(cbpp$period))[as.numeric(cbpp$period)])' does? As far as I understand, it generates a new variable consisting of random numbers with a particular mean, but I am not sure what exactly the command for the mean does.

Comment: You've got this one right. The example data i used `cbpp` doesn't have a numeric variable, and I didn't have an example with one at hand. But it does have a factor `period` (values: "1" to "4"). `period` is used as a fixed effect in the examples in `?glmer`, so I created a numeric proxy for the factor, by generating some random data with mean between 1 and 4 (equivalent of period). In short it sais `rnorm(nrow(cbpp), mean = (1:4)[match with period as numeric])`. `rnorm(n, mean = mu)` is simply generating random `n` numbers with means `mu` (`mu` may be more 1 number or  a vector of length n)

Comment: I could also have used `cbpp$nv <- rnorm(nrow(cbpp), mean = as.numeric(cbpp$period))`.

Answer (score 1):

Again, thank you so much, Oliver! For anybody who is interested in the answer regarding the last part of my question,

> Another problem is that the model contains several continuous
> predictors (which operate on similar scales) and 2 categorical
> predictors (one with 4 levels, one with six levels). The purpose of
> using the standardized coefficients would be to compare the impact of
> the categorical predictors to those of the continuous ones, and I'm
> not sure that standardized coefficients are the appropriate way to do
> so. Are standardized coefficients an acceptable approach?

you can find the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489409/using-standardized-coefficients-for-categorical-predictors-in-logistic-mixed-ef). The tl;dr is that using standardized regression coefficients is not the best approach for mixed models anyways, let alone one such as mine...